# XML Serialization Type Converter

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

In Json I can do this:

```
 [JsonProperty("type")]
 [JsonConverter(typeof(MyTpeConverter))]
 public BoxType myType { get; set; }


 .....
 public class BoxTypeEnumConverter : JsonConverter
 {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
     ....
    }
 }
```

Is this also possible when working with XML?

```
[XmlElement("isFolder")]
[XmlConvert()] // ???
public string IsFolder { get; set; }
```

My Xml File has e.g.

```
....
<isFolder>t</isFolder>
....
```

I want that "t" to be "true".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Threre are two ways:
Simple way: :)

```
[XmlElement("isFolder")]
public string IsFolderStr { get; set; }
[XmlIgnore]
public bool IsFolder { get{ ... conversion logic from IsFolderStr is here... }}
```

second way is to create a class that would handle custom convertion:

```
public class BoolHolder : IXmlSerializable
{
    public bool Value { get; set }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema() {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader) {
        string str = reader.ReadString();
        reader.ReadEndElement();

        switch (str) {
            case "t":
                this.Value = true;
    ...
    }
}
```

and replace definition of the property with BoolHolder:

> public BoolHolder IsFolder {get;set;}